# Windows10 GPO proxy setting applied without values

Tags: windows, active-directory, proxy, group-policy, windows-10

I'm trying to set up proxy via AD GPO. I followed [this guide](http://woshub.com/configure-internet-explorer-10-and-11-settings-using-gpo-in-windows-server-2012/) and configured the IE10 setting in user preferences (screen in Italian):

[image: gpo screenshot]

When I log into an account for which the policy applies I see the proxy as enabled but the proxy host field is empty! If I disable the proxy option and run `gpupdate /force` it will be enabled again, so it seems the policy is received... But why only *partially*?

[image: windows setting when gpo applied]

Client is Win10 Pro 19041.28.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enforcing the policy looks like it's not applied.
alternatively you can use registry
go to User Configuration > Preferences > Registry and create 3 registry parameters in the following registry key:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]:

    ProxyEnable (REG_DWORD) = 00000001;
    ProxyServer (REG_SZ) = fileserver.wdc.ca:3112;
    ProxyOverride (REG_SZ) = 192.*;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried setting the enforce flag but I've the same result. If I get no other options I'll go for the registry keys..

Comment: Using registry worked, thanks